Axios Delete Bad Request 400
I'm new in CRUD, especially in React JS. So, I'm using Axios in my current project. But when it comes to delete method on specific item (contact), it said error 400.
// delete contact
const deleteContact = async (id) => {
  console.log(id);
  const response = await axios.delete(`https://contact.herokuapp.com/contact/${id}`);

  return response.data;
};

Did I missing something in my delete method? I've tried to adding data after url, but seems doesn't work and I don't know which one data should I passed to. Thank you.
